# How can I capture video in Cordova (for Android and iOS) without being navigated to the native camera app of device?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am developing an app on Cordova (for Android and iPhone) that captures video and uploads it. I am using [Media Capture Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture) currently but it opens the native camera app of device to capture the video and returns the captured video back to my app which I can then upload.

I need to show a camera screen in the app itself, instead of being navigated to the native camera app to capture video. I want to know if this is possible using Cordova, or will I have to switch to development using native APIs?

Comment: You will need to build something custom using native code. If you want, you can build a plugin and still use cordova, but it sounds as if the app is very custom so going full native may be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DawsonLoudon.